# How to stop and restart apt-get

Tags: bash, apt-get

I have a very slow connection (~10KB/s) because my mobile carrier throttled me. Now, they will send about 32KB, then stop.

I am trying to install packages through apt-get, and I noticed that I can stop (ctrl-c) then restart the install and it will pick up from where it left off.

Doing this, I can get a little bit of data, then stop it, start it, and I get a little more data, otherwise (not stopping and restarting) I have to wait for about 15 seconds before more data comes

Is there a way I can automate this and have a script stop apt-get and start again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script that takes the package names as arguments and runs `apt-get` repeatedly, killing it after a few seconds. It runs `apt-get` in "download" mode, so it will only download, not install. You may want to tweak the `sleep` time depending on how quickly your provider throttles the download.

```
#!/bin/bash

me=$(basename $0)

if (($# == 0))
then
    printf "Usage: %s package [package]...\n" $me
    exit 1
fi

printf "Will install %d package(s).\n" $#
printf "This will run forever.\n"
printf "You can stop it by pressing ctrl-C when prompted.\n"
printf "If that fails, open another window and type 'killall %s'.\n" $me
read -p "Press 'Enter' to continue: "

while :
do
    timeout 3 apt-get -y -d install "$@"
    printf "Press ctrl-C within one second to stop\n"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Why not just use the GNU coreutils [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) tool? Should be no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Oh, very nice. Didn't know about that one. Thanks.

Comment: Rewritten to use `timeout`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it'd be better to try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process in the background. You might be able to use `fg` to *resume* once your connectivity returns.

To pause a job, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

For restarting the job again when you get the network signals:

```
fg %1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [apt-fast](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast), it downloads from multiple mirrors in parallel. Even if you disconnect from one it will continue download from other mirrors.
You can download and setup it right from the GitHub page of apt-fast it's very well documented.